# Install python modules without internet access

Tags: python

I need to write python scripts in a financial institution that does not allow internet access.

So how can I install python modules like requests, pandas, etc considering that there's no internet access and they do not allow you to proxy to the internet. You can't transfer files from a USB drive either.

Is it possible to work with python modules in such a limited environment?

Comment: They may have a local repository.  You need to speak w/their IT department.

Comment: How will you deploy scripts with no internet and no usb drive? And how did you download Python?

Comment: You cannot magically install libraries from thin air. You either need internet access or a method of file transfer so you could install from `.whl` files. Surely a solution can be found by speaking to your company's IT department (as mentioned above).

Comment: It sounds to me as if your status in the institution does not match your technical ambitions. If your bank is anything like the ones I have programmed in Python for, over 20 years, you have two options: (1) You ask the IT department (likely via your manager) to make the library modules you want available as part of the Python installation you already have. (2) You ask for recognition as a developer and get access to your institution's separate development environment. Developers typically have more freedom to download stuff, though you may still have to apply to get PyPI whitelisted.

Comment: Ok, that's a good suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Download the python package .whl files onto a local disk on the server you want the install the packages on.

(2) Make sure Pip is at least version 20.x

(3) Under windows from command prompt, run :

```
pip install <install_directory>\< .whl_file >
```

e.g.      pip install c:\temp\en_core_web_md-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

Process slightly different for Linux using RPM or YUM installers but in essence the same.

HTH